# Failed to find name servers of example.com/IN

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Wow. Made it through PHP, JS, bash, C++ before I had to ask a question. Apparently DNS is my Achilles heel. Here goes:

*Failed to find name servers of example.com/IN.*

I guess I'm lacking a basic understanding of DNS, though from what I gather you have a **Primary** NS where you edit a zone, any number of **Secondary/Slave** NS(s) which are basically host copies of the primary NS data, and **Forwarders** which then propagate this information about the Internet. Here are the contents of pertinent files:

*named.conf.options*:

```
forwarders{
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
};
```

*named.conf.local*:

```
acl slaves{
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
};
acl internals{
    xxx.x.x.x/x
    xxx.x.x.x/xx
};
view "external"{
    match-clients{ any; };
    recursion no;   
    zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/externals/db.example.com";
        allow-transfer { slaves; };
    };

    zone "x.x.xx.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/externals/db.xx";
    };
};
view "internal"{
    match-clients { internals; };
    recursion yes;
    zone "domain.tld" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/internals/db.example.com";
    };
};
```

*/externals/db.example.com*

```
$TTL    600
example.com.    IN      SOA ns1.example.com. root.mail.example.com. (
            2014071303      ; Serial
            28800           ; Refresh
            7200            ; Retry
            604800          ; Expire
            600 )           ; Negative Cache TTL
;
example.com.                    IN  NS      ns1.example.com.
example.com.                    IN  NS      ns0.xname.org.
example.com.                    IN  NS      ns1.xname.org.
example.com.                    IN  NS      ns2.xname.org.
example.com.                    IN  MX      10  mail.example.com.
example.com.                    IN  A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ns1.example.com.                IN  A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mail.example.com.               IN  A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
subdomain.example.com.          IN  A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www.example.com.                IN  CNAME   example.com.
www.subdomain.example.com.      IN  CNAME   subdomain.example.com.
```

-Registrar is set to use the XName nameservers and ns1.example.com.

-BIND restarts without any errors.

-Xname servers don't seem to have any information at all (maybe this is where the error lies?)

Comment: Your title and the error message make reference to `domain.com`, but the zonefiles and config all refer to `domain.tld`.  That might be the result of poor redaction, or it might be a real issue.  May I encourage you strongly not to redact the domain at all?  And failing that, at least to use `example.com` throughout, as provided for by the RFCs?

Comment: Lol, love how I redacted everything but left my real IP address up *facepalm*.

Comment: So I'm looking at the logs, and due to the 'external' 'internal' views, it seems to load the zones as 'example.com/IN/external'.

Comment: RE: forwarders, those are used to find information that is not available by tracing domains starting at the root nameservers. They are commonly used with private domains. When you include those forwarders in the main `options {};` block, you are telling the nameserver "do not try to look up other domains yourself, ask Google's servers instead". Root nameserver tracing is a hard concept to grasp early on, so my best advice is to run `dig +trace +additional yourdomain.example.com` and pick that apart.

Comment: Ok. removed the `forwarders`. `dig` stops with `dig: couldn't get address for 'nsX.example.com': no more` after correctly identifying the nameservers I listed with the registrar.

Comment: Hold up, had the completely wrong internal IP listed for port 53. I'll see if this changes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ladies and gentlemen, always carefully inspect your ports. Even when you think your have mastered port forwarding, you can still be prone to typographical errors that will leave you scratching your head until you get a good nights sleep.

tl; dr: `Port 53`

Comment: Also, sorry for the all the redacted info, but I have no idea how DNS works yet, so I want avoid any potential attacks before I'm secure.